# Mocking framework that supports mocking a method with delegate as parameter

Tags: c#, delegates, mocking, moq

I was very happy with Moq until I needed to test a method that takes a delegate as parameter and got an UnsupportedException. The issue is also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6302437/82047) and on Moq [issue list](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=300).

Is there any framework that supports this kind of mocking?

For example:

```
/// 
/// Interfaces
///

public interface IChannelFactory<T> {
    TReturn UseService<TReturn>(Func<T, TReturn> function);
}

public interface IService {
    int Calculate(int i);
}

///
/// Test
///

Mock<IChannelFactory<IService>> mock = new Mock<IChannelFactory<IService>>();

// This line results in UnsupportedException
mock.Setup(x => x.UseService(service => service.Calculate(It.IsAny<int>()))).Returns(10);
```

Comment: Is that actual code, or just some sample fragments? I ask because it doesn't look fully specified. For example, when you create your mock, shouldn't there be another level of generics in there? `new Mock<IChannelFactory<T>>`?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the correction. It was not copy-paste, thus the error.

Comment: In your setup line you pass an Expression ( service => service.Calculate() ). You need to pass somthing that resolves to a delegate such as a Func<> object.

Comment: @IanNorton The method is declared as taking a delegate, and you can most certainly pass a lambda expression to a delegate argument (with or without Moq). For example: `Func<int, int> f = x => x + 1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but this compiles and runs using your interfaces with Moq 4:

```
var mock = new Mock<IChannelFactory<IService>>();

mock.Setup(x => x.UseService(It.IsAny<Func<IService, int>>())).Returns(10);

int result = mock.Object.UseService(x => 0);

Console.WriteLine(result);  // prints 10
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228556/161457) for a more complex case.

Comment: Thanks, however this one will setup the mock for any method call in UseService, whereas I'm trying to select a specific one. I'm going to check the answer in the link soon.

Comment: The linked answer will probably get you what you want. I'd caution that you want to test one thing at a time, which usually means keeping your mocks and stubs simple. The more complex you make them, the more you're testing your mocks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue recently, and here's how to use moq (v4.0.10827) to test the correct method and parameters are called. (Hint: you need two layers of mocks.)

```
//setup test input
int testInput = 1;
int someOutput = 10;

//Setup the service to expect a specific call with specific input
//output is irrelevant, because we won't be comparing it to anything
Mock<IService> mockService = new Mock<IService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockService.Setup(x => x.Calculate(testInput)).Returns(someOutput).Verifiable();

//Setup the factory to pass requests through to our mocked IService
//This uses a lambda expression in the return statement to call whatever delegate you provide on the IService mock
Mock<IChannelFactory<IService>> mockFactory = new Mock<IChannelFactory<IService>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockFactory.Setup(x => x.UseService(It.IsAny<Func<IService, int>>())).Returns((Func<IService, int> serviceCall) => serviceCall(mockService.Object)).Verifiable();

//Instantiate the object you're testing, and pass in the IChannelFactory
//then call whatever method that's being covered by the test
//
//var target = new object(mockFactory.Object);
//target.targetMethod(testInput);

//verifying the mocks is all that's needed for this unit test
//unless the value returned by the IService method is used for something
mockFactory.Verify();
mockService.Verify();
```

Comment: That's interesting! Thanks, I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Moles. It supports delegates as mocks.

[Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/)